# Pause characters not recognized by Android's tel:// URL

Tags: android, url, tel

Tapping on a tel:// url from an Android device, the pause characters ('p' or commas) aren't correctly recognized. Is there any workraound or solution about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the address book, you can use:

> +18001234567;1000#,#

However, links from email, calendar, etc. don't interpret all of the tel:// characters as part of the phone number.
Apparently, [Apple sued for copyright infringement](http://mashable.com/2011/12/19/apple-patent-victory/) and won.